# REST and passing authentication token

Tags: html, ruby, json, rest

I'm writing my first REST program and I'm struggling with passing the session token. Also I have looked in several forums for similar issues questions, but with no luck.

So I have the following piece of Ruby chunk code (not the whole script):

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

headers_lbvserver = {
    'Content-Type' => application/vnd.com.citrix.netscaler.lbvserver+json',
    'accept' => :json
}

add_lbvserver = RestClient::Request.execute(
    :method => :post,
    :url => url_lbvserver,
    :headers => headers_lbvserver,
    :payload => payload_lbvserver,
    :cookie => {'NITRO_AUTH_TOKEN=' => token_login}
)
```

So I have already received the token from a previous REST post, but I can't passing it trough when i maken my second call to the object. It comes with the following error: 400 Bad Request (RestClient::BadRequest)

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the docs of RestClient, it looks like you are declaring your cookie incorrectly. You don't need to have an equal sign after the cookie name:

`:cookie => {'NITRO_AUTH_TOKEN=' => token_login}`

should be

`:cookie => {'NITRO_AUTH_TOKEN' => token_login}`

Comment: I already tried that, but with no success. Thanks for your reply!